# Custom Range/Variable Set with jQuery UI Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, uislider

I wanted to see if I could make a custom data set to use with [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/).  I'm working on a site that has dress sizes that come in the range of:
[ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 16W, 18W, 20W ]

The issue I'm having arises right after 18, when it jumps to "wide" sizes that are a bit unique.

Before I added in the 16W, 18W, and on sizes, I created a working slider using the following code:

```
$("#slider-size .slider").slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 18,
  step: 2,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $(".rsize").text(ui.value);
  }
});
```

*The last argument in that function changes a text value when the slider is changed.*

**Does anyone know how to go about adding in the 16W, 18W, etc to the end of this list?**

Thanks!

Comment: please see my edit below... cheers! :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

for custom sizes, you may use another array for your labels:

```
var sizes = ["0","2","4","6","8","10","12","14","16","18","16W","18W","20W"];
$("#slider-size .slider").slider({
  min: 0,
  max: sizes.length - 1,
  step: 1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $(".rsize").text(sizes[ui.value]);
  }
});
```

Now, to add or remove sizes, just modify the `sizes` array.

Answer (score 7):

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KdAUE/)

```
$("#slider-size .slider").slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 24, // max is 24
  step: 2,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    var s = ui.value;
    switch(ui.value) {
       case 20:
         s = '16W';
         break;
       case 22:
         s = '18W';
         break;
       case 24:
         s = '12W';
         break;
    }
    $(".rsize").text(s);
  }
});
```

----- or ------

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ckFBE/)

```
$("#slider-size .slider").slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 24, // max is 24
  step: 2,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
      $(".rsize").text((ui.value >18)?(ui.value-4)+'W':ui.value);
  }
});​
```