# get values of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, dojo

I have this code, and my objective is get the array object.
No errors in firebug, but no value is showed (always `undefined`) . What is the correct way to do this ?

```
var sizes = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];

var s = new dijit.form.HorizontalSlider({
                value:1,
                name:"i"+[i],
                onChange:function(sizes, val){ 
                    dojo.byId('value'+[i]).value = sizes[val];
                    },
                minimum:1,
                maximum:sizes.length -1,
                discreteValues:sizes.length,

            },node);
```

In jquery looks like:

```
var sizes = ["0","2","4","6","8","10","12","14","16","18","16W","18W","20W"];
$("#slider-size .slider").slider({
  min: 0,
  max: sizes.length - 1,
  step: 1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $(".rsize").text(sizes[ui.value]);
  }
});
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336709/custom-range-variable-set-with-jquery-ui-slider)

Comment: This doesn't look like valid Javascript. Did you omit an enclosing object-literal?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you are trying to do?  the `onChange` event function only takes a single parameter, 'value'.

Comment: i have a slider, and basically i want the output. For example if i choose the second value i want b and not 2.

Comment: "I want the output" is hardly a well-stated set of functional requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
minimum:0,
```

is the problem. Thanks