# jQuery input slider values with mixed interval

Tags: jquery, uislider, intervals

I need a jQuery input slider like [noUiSlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/).

(I don't like the [jQuery UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) because of the iframe usage.)

**Problem**

***I would like a "mixed" interval in the slider, set the numbers myself, like this:***

1, 10, 25, 50, 100, 1000, 10000

- How is that done?
- Can it be done with noUiSlider?
- If not, is it supported by any other slider plugin?
- Range feature is not required but a callback on change is needed.

Comment: I don't get the "mixed interval" part : could you give more details ?

Comment: What do you mean with `iframe usage`?

Comment: @LeGEC Like this but not with an iframe solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336709/custom-range-variable-set-with-jquery-ui-slider

Comment: @alexn I was too quick with element inspecting. The iframe was just a way to preview the function from another page.